# manualColumnMove not updating the column width

Tags: css

Have anyone faced this bug.
    The manualColumnMove is moving the column alright, but not taking the column width along.
Please check : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fxfaxtz1/)

```
body {background: white; margin: 20px;}
h2 {margin: 20px 0;}
```

The columns are getting moved correctly but the width are not getting refreshed resulting in a data wrap and messing up the entire HOT.
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line of JS code and try.

```
/* colWidths: [65, 90, 50, 90, 50, 70, 45, 50, 50, 50, 90, 50, 70, 90, 60, 50, 20, 50, 50, 50, 50, 70], */
```

Comment: Cannot do that. I need the column widths to fit the data exactly as I wanted to as per the requirement. Once any column is moved, HOT should take the underlying width of that column as well. This is a very default requirement I guess.